# Spring AMQP: Send reply from POJO listener failure because of missing reply-to property

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to write a simple code sample which sends a message to an exchange, receive it with a listener and send a message back.

This is how I send the message:

```
private static void pingpong(Object messageListener) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");

    // set up the queue, exchange, binding on the broker
    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);
    Queue queue = new Queue(QUEUE);
    admin.declareQueue(queue);
    TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE);
    admin.declareExchange(exchange);
    admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.*"));

    // set up the listener and container
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE);
    container.start();

    // send something and receive result.
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cf);
    Object result = template.convertSendAndReceive(EXCHANGE, "foo.bar", "ping");
    System.out.println("Received: " + result);
}
```

The code for the listener:

```
public static class PingPongReceiver {
    public String handleMessage(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + in);
        return "pong";
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
pingpong(new MessageListenerAdapter(new PingPongReceiver()));
```

But sending the reply fails with the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1345)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload 'pong'
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:213)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.getReplyToAddress(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:209)
    ... 12 more
```

I have problems figuring out how to send the reply using an anonymous, non-durable queue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing makes no sense; the `RabbitTemplate.convertAndReceive()` sets up the replyTo ([Direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) if the broker supports it, otherwise a temporary queue).

I just copied and pasted your code and it worked fine for me...

```
Received: ping
Received: pong
```

Perhaps you have an old, stale, message in the queue that doesn't have a replyTo?

You can purge the queue using the admin UI.

I also tested your code with

```
Queue queue = new AnonymousQueue();
...
container.setQueueNames(queue.getName());
```

and it worked fine too.

By the way, when creating Spring Beans manually, it's recommended that you call `afterPropertiesSet` (if the bean is an initializing bean).

```
container.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Finally, you should stop the container and destroy the connection:

```
container.stop();
cf.destroy();
```